# how to load data into another html page after a php server read?

Tags: jquery

The code below reads data from the p.php file. From here, how would I load the data into another html file named data.html located on the server into id #insertData? I would like to use the jquery html(data) method as a method to insert the data

```
       $.post("p.php",{sendword: test2, Testtable2: table_name2}, function(data)
       {

       });
```

Comment: why cant you directly load it into data.html?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your jquery code is on the same page where you want to insert the content, in that case, your callback can just be `$('#insertData').html(responsetext);

Comment: How do I identify the remote html (data.html) file in the selector part of the jquery function?

Comment: I think you can't, since javascript runs on one page. This is because javascript runs on the client side, which means that your other html page may not even be loaded.